# Is this true for all $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, permutations, real-numbers

Let $a_{1}\leq ...\leq a_{n}$ and $b_{1}\leq ...\leq b_{n}$ be real numbers . Then for any bijection $f:\{1,2,...n\}\to\{1,2,...,n\}$ , $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i}-b_{f(i)}|^{2}\geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i}-b_{i}|^{2}$

I want to know if this is true or not for any natural numbers $n$ and if yes then how to prove it.

My very short attempt :-

I think it is true.
If we view $f$ as an element of $S_{n}$. Then if $f$ is any transposition WLOG say $(12)$ . Then I can show it. But I am struggling to do it . I tried by decomposing into product of transpositions but that product is not of disjoint transpositions so I am unable to find a way to deal with the general case.

Edit:-I saw something similar in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711713/hoffman-wielandt-theorem-proof) . That is for if $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$ are eigen values of normal matrices then it is true. But I don't know how to prove it for real numbers. What I mean to say is that it would be highly elaborate one to prove this fact about real numbers . Also I don't really know the proof of Hoffmann-Weilandt theorem so it would also be unethical to say the least.

Can someone help me by showing me how it should be done?

Comment: My gut says this isn't true.  You'd be saying the right-hand side is minimum across all possible permutations $f$.  Seems unreasonable.

Comment: @Randall No? With the $a_i$ in increasing order, keeping the $b_i$ also in increasing order seems the intuitively best way to get a minimum distance.

Comment: Ah maybe you're right.  I missed the ordering of the $b_i$s. @aschepler

Comment: @Randall I saw something similar in the Hoffmann-Weilandt theorem . That is for if $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$ are eigen values of normal matrices then it is true. But I don't know how to prove it for real numbers. What I mean to say is that it would be highly elaborate one to prove this fact about real numbers . Also I don't really know the proof of Hoffmann-Weilandt theorem so it would also be unethical to say the least.

Comment: Would be an interesting and (for me) not at all intuitive result.

Comment: Are the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ always true ?

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888769/inequality-involving-rearrangement-sum-i-1n-x-i-y-sigmai-ge-su?rq=1) was in "related"  . And it seems that the claim is true.

Comment: Nice arguments in the linked answer

Comment: @Randall The accepted answer says it's true for all convex functions . I think it's better if I just look in the reference suggested there. So please feel free to close it as a duplicate if the users thinks so.  . Also regardless , I would like it if there are some new answers too. Thanks in any case !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f$ be optimal (minimising the sum) and not the identity. Then there exist $i<j$ with $f(i)>f(j)$.
By swapping only these two, the relevant summands change from
$$(a_i-b_{f(i)})^2+(a_j-b_{f(j)})^2$$
to
$$(a_i-b_{f(j)})^2+(a_j-b_{f(i)})^2.$$
The difference between these two is (expand and cancel the common squares)
$$2a_ib_{f(j)}-2a_iv_{f(i)}+2a_jb_{f(i)}-2a_jb_{f(j)}=2(a_i-a_j)(b_{f(j)}-b_{f(i)})$$
And thus positive, i.e., an improvement - contradicting optimality of $f$.